# Convergence of identically distributed normal random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, convergence

I had this example in my machine learning lecture.

> Let $X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be identically distributed (but not independent) copies of $X_1$ drawn from $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Then $X_n$ converges to $Y = -X_1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

There isn't any explanation for why this sequence of random variables converges to $Y$.

Convergence in the sense

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}(t)$ where $F_{X_n}$ is the CDF of $X_n$.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Converges in what sense? In distribution? In probability? Almost surely?

Comment: Is this a verbatim copy of the statement? Or, do you have a reference to it? Certainly is converges in distribution to $Y$, but that is trivial. (Why?)

Comment: What does it mean to be identical copied of $X_1$? Is $X_2=X_3=...=X_n=X_1$? How are they dependent? To be dependent would mean $P(X_1,X_i) \neq P(X_1) P(X_i) \forall i \in [2,n]$. What then is $P(X_1,X_i)$?

Comment: If they are identical as in the standard meaning of identical, i.e. $X_2=X_1$, they are certainly dependent. In which case it is absolutely trivial.

Comment: @Xi'an: I assume you are thinking of the convergence in distribution then. For, in any other (standard) mode of convergence, the result is obviously false under the meaning you are giving to "identical copy". :)

Comment: If they are identical copies, then the sequence is just $X_1, X_1, ..., X_1, ...$, so the sequence converges in distribution to the CDF of $X_1$, trivially. Since $X_1$ has a standard normal distribution, $-X_1$ also has a standard normal distribution. So, if by converging to $-X_1$ you mean that the CDF converges to that of $-X_1$, then the result is trivial.

Comment: When you write "Identical and independent in the same sense as iid" you are missing a word... iid means _independent and identically distributed_! Identical means that $X_1=X_2=\ldots$, in which case the distribution (and the cdf) remain constant across indices.

Comment: And just to insist on precise wording, this is not a _statistics_ problem but a _probability_ problem, illustrating the meaning of _convergence in distribution_ (or _in law_).

Comment: _iid_ means _independent and identically distributed_: you are missing _distributed_...

Comment: What is your point now?! We are still left in the dark as to whether or not you mean identical (as in $X=Y$) or identically distributed (as in $F_X=F_Y$ in your question! If the former, Macro above gave you the proper arguments to solve this problem.

Comment: @Transcendence: In my estimation, Xi'an is using a form of the [Socratic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_questioning). It's quite commonly used on this site. :)

Comment: @Transcendence: Might I kindly suggest you reread the comments from start to finish, taking special care to read the wording. Three users were unsure of what you were asking and so asked for clarification in one form or another. This is not proof-positive that the question needs refinement, but it's strong evidence. In Xi'an's first response to you (his second overall comment) he specifically indicated the word (*distributed*) he thought was missing. I find your long comment starting with "No. I'm not trying to define..." quite confusing, especially in like of the other comments before that...

Comment: ...so I genuinely think you left @Xi'an (and others) confused at that point. Remember that your reference to "Identical and independent in the same sense as iid" came in the comments, not in the main question, which is what Xi'an was then trying to help clarify with you as the wording in your comment and in the question conflicted with one another. Finally, I'd urge you to consider that people come here to both ask and answer questions. If they're here engaging with you, it's almost never the case that they're doing so to be purposefully obtuse. Cheers. :)

Comment: @cardinal: thank you for the attempt at defusing the escalation!

Comment: @Xi'an: I think your main idea of showing an explicit example of a dependent sequence is a good one. I will incorporate this into my answer shortly with a reference to our discussion (now deleted) in the comments to my answer. Thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 12):

The example in your lecture is making a reference to *convergence in distribution*. Below, I try to go through some of the details of what this means.

**A general definition**

A sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ **converges in distribution** to a limiting random variable $X_\infty$ if their associated distribution functions $F_n(x) = \mathbb P(X_n \leq x)$ converge *pointwise* to $F_\infty(x) = \mathbb P(X_\infty \leq x)$ for every point $x$ at which $F_\infty$ is continuous.

Note that this statement actually says *nothing* about the random variables $X_n$ themselves or even the measure space that they live on. It is *only* making a statement about the behavior of their distribution functions $F_n$. In particular, no reference or appeal to any independence structure is made.

**The case at hand**

In this particular case, the problem statement itself assumes that each of the $X_n$ have the same distribution function $F_n = F$. This is analogous to a constant sequence of numbers $(y_n)$. Certainly if $y_n = y$ for all $n$ then $y_n \to y$. In fact, we can "map" our convergence-in-distribution problem down to such a situation in the following way.

If we fix an $x$ and consider the sequence of *numbers* $y_n = F_n(x) = F(x)$, we see that $y_1,y_2,\ldots$ is a *constant* sequence and so, obviously, converges (to $F(x)$, of course). This holds for any $x$ we choose, and so the *functions* $F_n$ converge pointwise for every $x$ (in this case) to $F$.

To finish things off, we note that $F(x) = \mathbb P(X_1 \leq x) = \mathbb P(-X_1 \leq x)$ by the symmetry of the normal distribution, so $F$ is also the distribution of $-X_1$. Hence $X_n \to -X_1$ in distribution.

**Some equivalent and related statements for this example**

To perhaps clarify the meaning of this notion further, consider the following (true!) statements about convergence in distribution, all of which use the same sequence you've defined.

- $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ converges in distribution to $X_1$.
- Fix any $k$. $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ converges in distribution to $X_k$.
- Fix any $k$. $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ converges in distribution to $-X_k$.
- Define $Y_n = (-1)^n X_n$. Then, $Y_n \to X_1$ in distribution.
- **Slightly trickier**. Let $\epsilon_n$ be random variables such that $\epsilon_n$ is independent of $X_n$ (but, not necessarily of other $\epsilon_k$ or $X_k$) and taking the values $+1$ and $-1$ with probability 1/2, each. Define $Z_n = \epsilon_n X_n$. Then, the sequence $Z_1, Z_2,\ldots$ converges in distribution to $X_1$. This sequence also converges in distribution to $-X_1$ and $\pm X_k$ for any fixed $k$.

**Explicit examples incorporating dependence**

The easiest way to construct examples in which the $X_i$ are dependent is to use functions of a latent sequence of iid standard normals. The **central limit theorem** provides a canonical example. Let $Z_1,Z_2,\ldots$ be an iid sequence of standard normal random variables and take 
$$X_n = n^{-1/2} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \>.$$
Then each $X_n$ is standard normal, so $X_n \to -X_1$ in distribution, but the sequence is obviously dependent.

Xi'an provided another nice (related) example in a comment (now deleted) to this answer. Let $X_n = (1-2 \mathbb I_{(Z_1+\cdots+Z_{n-1}\geq 0})) Z_n$ where $\mathbb I_{(\cdot)}$ denotes the indicator function. The necessary conditions are, again, satisfied.

Other such sequences can be constructed in a similar way.

**An aside on the relationship to other modes of convergence**

There are three other standard notions of convergence of random variables: *almost-sure convergence*, *convergence in probability* and $L_p$ *convergence*. Each of these are (a) "stronger" than convergence in distribution in the sense that convergence in any of these three implies convergence in distribution and (b) each of these three, in contrast to convergence in distribution, requires that the random variables at least be defined on a common measure space.

To achieve almost-sure convergence, convergence in probability or $L_p$ convergence, we often have to assume some additional structure on the sequence. However, something slightly peculiar happens in the case of a sequence of normally distributed random variables.

**An interesting property of sequences of normal random variables**

**Lemma**: Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of zero-mean normal random variables defined on the same space with variances $\sigma_n^2$. Then, $X_n \xrightarrow{\,p\,} X_\infty$ in probability if and only if $X_n \xrightarrow{\,L_2\,} X_\infty$, in which case $X_\infty \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ where $\sigma^2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sigma_n^2$.

The point of the lemma is three-fold. First, in the case of a sequence of normal random variables, convergence in probability and in $L_2$ are equivalent which is not usually the case. Second, no (in)dependence structure is assumed in order to guarantee this convergence. And, third, the limit  is guaranteed to be normally distributed (which is *not* otherwise obvious!) regardless of the relationship between the variables in the sequence. (This is now discussed in a little more detail in [this follow-up question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24362).)