# How does one prove $\int_{0}^{a}B(t)dt\sim \mathcal N(0,\frac{a^3}{3})$?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

Let $B(t)$ is Brownian Motion. I want to prove the integral $\int_{0}^{a}B(t)dt$ has normal distribution , $\mathcal N(0,\frac{a^3}{3})$.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? What properties of Brownian motion are you using? [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24378/2970) might be helpful.

Comment: This question was simultaneously [crossposted](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/570625/7003) to math.SE, where it has an accepted answer. For future reference, please do *not* crosspost simultaneously. [This meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) contains more details regarding the philosophy behind this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is to consider a partition like $\bigtriangleup_a=\dfrac{a}{n}$ for $n>0$ and $a_k=k\bigtriangleup_a$ for $k=0,...,n-1$. Here $B(t)$ is a continuous function so you can approximate it by a Riemann integral as $Y_a=\bigtriangleup_a\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B(a_k)$. The normality distribution of $Y_a$ comes from the fact that you have a linear summation of normally distributed random variables. The $E(Y_a)$ is also easy to find because $E(B(a_k))=0$. To find the variance you need to find $E(Y_a^2)$. Hint: try to write it in term of a double integral. If you have problems in finding $E(Y_a^2)$, then have a look at [here](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/StochCalc2004/notes/l6.pdf). But try to get it yourself after reading some lines since this is a very standard question.

Comment: Just as a side note: One needs to consider a little more than just the partition argument. Namely, the associated limit must be shown to also be a normal random variable. This is true, but doesn't simply follow "naively" from the fact that each element of the sequence is normal. (+1)

Comment: My intention was not to provide a rigorous proof. But it is good that you pointed this out.

Comment: That's fine; I was not criticizing, but rather simply making an auxiliary remark, in part so that casual readers would not take the phrase "all you need to do..." too literally. :-)