# Finding the limiting distribution

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, poisson-distribution

I was given an exercise to do that sounded something like this:

The Arizona football team scored $45$ goals in $19$ games in the 2007/08 season. If $y_i$ denotes the number of goals scored in the $i$-th game, consider the following model:

$Y_1,\dots,Y_n \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ independently with $\lambda > 0$.

What is the limiting distribution of

$$T_n = \sqrt n\cdot\frac1{n\sqrt\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\lambda)$$

as $n\to\infty$?

Use $T_n$ to construct a $95$% confidence interval for $\lambda$.

Could someone please tell me what a limiting distribution is and how to find it? After that I should be able to handle the question on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: Some hints: (1) The question has nothing to do with Arizona football (soccer), so you can ignore the first two paragraphs. (2) You *cannot* use $T_n$ to construct a confidence interval--but you can use it to construct an *approximate* confidence interval for "large" $n$. (3) You should be able to recognize a standardized random variable in the expression for $T_n$: that should immediately bring to mind the Central Limit Theorem. (4) The CLT makes a conclusion about a limiting distribution.

Comment: Some of the discussion in the comments and answer to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21847/2970) might be somewhat helpful. Read it at a high level; don't get lost in the weeds. :-)